# Use font awesome in select option

Tags: php, font-awesome

I have a PSD like this.

[image: psd]

I am trying to add font-awesome to select option, but it doesn't work.

This is what I get.

[image: simple]

This is my code:

```
<?php 
    for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?= $i ?>">&#xf2bb; &#xf2bb; &#xf2bb; &#xf2bb; &#xf2bb;</option>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Unicode as value attribute in option. like this:

```
<option value="&#f005;">
```

use `font-weight: 400` for outline star and `font-weight: 900` for filled star.

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi what happened?